# Magento2- How to get the price (product price+ static price) without catalog price rule applied

Tags: magento2, price, catalog, catalog-price-rules

Magento2- How to get the product price without catalog price rule applied.

I want to add an additional price percentage to all the product before the catalog rule applied.

Basically what I want is :

**Product price(without catalog rule applied)+10% of product price and after that catalog price rule should be applied.**

Answer (score 0):

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollection;

class yourClass
{
    /**
     * @var ProductCollection
     */ 
    private $_productCollection;

```
public function __construct(
    ProductCollection $productCollection,
```

){
        $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
}

public function UpdateProductPrice()
{

$collection = $this->_productCollection->create();

```
 foreach ($collection as $product) {
 $initialPrice=$product->getPrice();
 $saticPrice=0.1*$initialPrice();
 $fianlPrice=$initialPrice+$staticPrice;
 $product->setPrice($finalPrice);
 $product->save()
 }
```

}

}

Comment: I don't want to save in database I just to show the price on frontend

Comment: In listing page or in category page

Comment: every where in frontned : Listing , detail, catalog, checkout etc

Comment: if that's the case you need to over ride so many phtml files instead of that changing the price in the product level is better

Comment: Is there not a common function for a price where I can change the price and it will reflect everywhere.

Comment: if you what to reflect the price every where change the price in the product level

Comment: But i don't to change in DB